# Find parametric equations for the cylinder of radius $3$ whose axis is the line $x = y = z$

Tags: differential-geometry

Since the cylinder is a ruled surface, and the director curve is given by $\delta (u) = (1,1,1)$, I have to find the parametrization for the directrix (base curve) on the new axis. I'm given the hint that I'm supposed to find two vectors perpendicular on the plane $x + y + z = 0$, but I'm unable to visualize why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1,1,1)$ is a normal vector to the plane $x+y+z=0$ so that plane is perpendicular to the cylinder and the intersection with it is a circle. You need two perpendicular unit vectors on that plane. Just take $(1,-1,0)$ and $(1,1,-2)$. After normalizing you get
$$
U=(1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2},0),\quad V=(1/\sqrt{6},1/\sqrt{6},-2/\sqrt{6})
$$
Then a parametrization of the circle would be
$$
X(t)=3\cos t \, U+3\sin t \,V
$$
And finally you can parametrize the cylinder as
$$
X(t,s)=3\cos t \, U+3\sin t \,V+s N
$$
Where $N=(1,1,1)$.

Comment: So, we would be able to "shift" the perpendicular unit vectors such that the intersection of those vectors was the center of the circle?

Comment: These are free vectors. You can think of them as applied at the origin, and contained in the plane of the circle.